# Bulk import multiple CSV using command line SSIS DTEXEC.exe

Tags: csv, import, ssis, bulk, dtexec

I have 200+ CSVs and I'd like to bulk insert it into SQL Server using SSIS command-line: DTEXEC.exe. Is this something that is possible to do with one command?

I have to import hundreds of files daily automatically and I believe the most efficient way is to do a command line.

I'm assuming it involves the foreach loop editor.

If there's a better way to do this, I'd like to know as well!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all files have the same column layout, you could use a [Foreach Loop Container](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141724.aspx) with the enumerator type set to `Foreach File`. [Example looping through Excel files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345182.aspx)